# How to Trigger $.getJSON().fail()?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

How do I change my AJAX request by forcing a 404 error or the like in my JQuery call so that my function .fail() responds so I can test it?

```
$.getJSON(urlthing, {
    maxResults: 5,
    pageToken: token,
    key: "something"
})
.done(function(data){
     DO SOME CRAZY STUFF
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){console.log("Request Failed: "+ textStatus+ ', ' + error);});
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `url` string to a invalid value will give a 404

```
$.getJSON('urlthing' + 'testurl', {
    maxResults: 5,
    pageToken: token,
    key: "something"
})
.done(function(data){
     DO SOME CRAZY STUFF
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error){console.log("Request Failed: "+ textStatus+ ', ' + error);});
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For unit testing purposes, you can use packages like [Sinon JS](http://sinonjs.org/) to intercept AJAX requests and provide fake responses.